# How to keep the SQL queries used in Website and APIs common

Tags: mysql, rest, database-design, architecture

I am working on a web platform that uses MySQL as DB. I am also making a mobile app for the platform and using APIs to fetch data from DB. 
What is the mechanism to keep a single SQL queries set that can cater to web and Mobile App APIs without compromising their distinct requirements.
If there is a fix to sql queries I have to do it twice and I want to avoid that as its error prone.

Comment: What are the unique requirements?
Can't you just expose a common web service to both?

Comment: You are right, not everything is unique. But to make the best of UI on Mobile and web, the way content is presented is different and these results in a change in SQL query

Comment: fair enough :-) Personally unless there is significant and costly difference between the two, I would find a way to make it work. The solution from rob conklin is essentially saying the same thing - just in my SQL powered web service there isn't the concept of inheritance.

Comment: I found this link that is apt for my requirements. I am trying to understand the performance impact of dynamic WHERE clause based approach though.        https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_where

Comment: You can do it without dynamic SQL e.g. select * from table where (param1 = param1input or param1 is null) AND (param2 = param2input or param2 is null).

Comment: So you are saying that the where clause becomes dynamic based on the input Parameter. Thats interesting. Will give this approach a shot. Thanks Jonno

Answer (score 1):

Create the Data Access Layer as a library.  Adhere to the [open-closed principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) to allow your objects to be extended as needed to handle the peculiarities of your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I am using Php and Codeigniter in my project. Let me check if this concept works there.